# Why the following two methods generating the same IL?

Tags: c#, il

```
 public static class Extensions
{
    public static T Include<T>(this System.Enum type,T value) where T:struct 
    {
      return ((T) (ValueType) (((int) (ValueType) type | (int) (ValueType) value)));

    }
    public static T Include1<T>(this System.Enum type, T value) 
    {
        return ((T)(object)((int)(object)type | (int)(object)value));

    }
}
```

If you see the IL generated for these two methods they look the same or am i missing something...
why boxing is happening for the first Include method?

Comment: you should add the IL...

Comment: ValueType is a class. Your casting from a value type to a class in both methods, hence, they both Box the reference.

Comment: (updated answer with some options for doing this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ValueType` is a reference-type. Honest. It is only a struct when it is `T`. You would need to replace all the `ValueType` with `T` for it not to box. However, there will be no inbuilt cast from `T` to `int`... so: you can't. You will have to box. Plus, not all enums are `int`-based (your box-as-enum, unbox-as-int will fail for a `enum Foo : ushort`, for example).

In C# 4.0, `dynamic` might be a cheeky way to do this:

```
public static T Include<T>(this T type, T value) where T : struct
{
    return ((dynamic)type) | value;
}
```

Otherwise, some meta-programming (essentially to do what `dynamic` does, but manually):

```
static void Main()
{
    var both = Test.A.Include(Test.B);
}
enum Test : ulong
{
    A = 1, B = 2
}

public static T Include<T>(this T type, T value) where T : struct
{
    return DynamicCache<T>.or(type, value);
}
static class DynamicCache<T>
{
    public static readonly Func<T, T, T> or;
    static DynamicCache()
    {
        if(!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new InvalidOperationException(typeof(T).Name + " is not an enum");
        var dm = new DynamicMethod(typeof(T).Name + "_or", typeof(T), new Type[] { typeof(T), typeof(T) }, typeof(T),true);
        var il = dm.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Or);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        or = (Func<T, T, T>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, T, T>));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it will work. It'll say that there is no conversion from `int` to `T`

Comment: @CodeInChaos - yes, I realised that while pressing "submit" - press F5